# i18n-node-2, Express and a Handlebars helper

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a Handlebars helper for [i18n-node-2](https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2) so that I can use localised strings directly from the view, but using the Express helper to register i18n in the first place, I can't then get an instance of i18n that I can use inside the helper.

The relevant code:

```
var i18n = require('i18n-2');
```

Registering i18n with Express:

```
i18n.expressBind(app, {
  locales: ['en', 'de'],
  cookieName: 'locale',
  extension: ".json"
});
```

Creating my helper:

```
hbs.registerHelper('__', function() {
  // What I would *like* to do, but the 'i18n' instance here is the wrong one
  return i18n.__.apply(i18n, arguments);
});
```

Basically, inside the helper I need the the instance of i18n as created by `i18n.expressBind()`, which calls `i18n.init()`. Short of modifying the source code to return this instance, is there another way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. i18n-node-2 places the lookup functions `__` and `__n` in the locals collection, which you can get to from the context that Handlebars gives you when running the helper:

```
hbs.registerHelper('__', function(key, context) {  
  return context.data.root.__(key);
});
```

.. which works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

To build off of @SteveHobbs' answer, if you have a helper that's expecting an arbitrary number of parameters and even an options hash, you could do the following:

```
hbs.registerHelper('foo', function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
      last = args.pop(),
      options = last.hash,
      context = last.data.root;

  // Show what's available:
  console.log('From foo helper:');
  console.log('args:', args);
  console.log('options:', options);
  console.log('context:', context);
});
```